# Python - Can I get all Code Paths that use a name in a module (more specifically call a function)

Tags: python, invoke, introspection

Assuming that all usages of name `my_function` from module `asfd.zxcv.qwer` are static, and all usages of all the code invoking that method is static (and the code invoking THAT code, and so on), is there a tool that gets all the code paths leading to my `my_function`?

I can't use `grep` because there's quite a few invocations we're talking about.
I can't use an IDE, navigating from call to call, for the same reason.

I expect hundreds of calls, and tens of initial entry points (meaning code that's not called from anywhere, and must be called either by 3rd party frameworks, or manually).

Post code spoilers if you really want to, because i can see how this question can lead to a very fun programming experience - but i don't encourage this.

[EDIT]:
My Purpose is **NOT** profiling.
I just want to exhaustively search my codebase for invocations of a method that i want to deprecate, and I want to see what else I should deprecate together with it. It's quite a 'dangerous' code, from a business perspective, and I want to refactor everything converning it - AND i can't just remove it, or no-op it, before knowing what it affects.

[EDIT]:
Apparently i'm not allowed to ask for software recommendations, so i guess i have to limit myself to open-source projects, and standard library modules.

Comment: What is the purpose of this - if you are thinking about performance, use a profiler.

Comment: This is not the place to ask software recommendations. If this isn't what you mean, than you probably have to edit the text to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Software recommendations also covers open-source and standard library - if you want tools, have a look at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/asking